# FILTER function in non-continuous sections

Tags: google-sheets

I have seen similar questions asked but have not found a good working solution.

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgsdO55nTtINZXJGVbNr-u6tup4p3P7hIuwNwxtyMbo/edit?usp=sharing) which has two sections which need to be filtered into a separate tab.
The first column is names, all of which have the first three columns of data in common. After that, depending on the name, I need to draw in three other columns (non-adjacent to the first section) using a formula in a different tab.

I have created a tab (Nancy) with the first FILTER function in play (the first three columns of data), but cannot find a way to filter in the other set of data using a separate function.

I would like to make tabs for the all other names which will filter data as new information is entered on the master sheet.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed!  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86953/filter-function-in-non-continuous-sections#comment74115_86953) of [pnuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/60716/pnuts)

> I'm not sure what you want but perhaps this might be a step forwards:
>   `=query(Sheet1!A1:X15,"select A,B,C,D,H,I,J where A = 'Nancy' ",1)`.
>   In other words, what actual results do you want/where from your sample
>   data?